# How to include a flexible object inside a mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema similar to this:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   flexible_object: // some object

   // a bunch of other not flexible stuff
})
```

For a set of complicated reasons, I do not know the structure of the flexible object.

How could I store an object in mongoose like this?

Also, I can't use JSON.stringify() to store it as a string because I want to be able to query it.

Comment: You can use mongoose mixed schema type.You might want to refer this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment you need a [mixed schema type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed).
You can simply do it by defining an empty object:

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   flexible_object: {},

   // a bunch of other not flexible stuff
})
```